# Extract cell value by its name in Excel document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to Extract some value from an Excel spreadsheet by using cell name instead of using cell reference (row,column).

The reason of that is because user want to modify their Excel (add or remove lines/column) and don't want to take care for the cell reference of my rails process. The alternative of that is to use cell naming function into Excel spreadsheet I think.

Is there a way to do that?

if yes, what GEM parser can be the best (spreadsheet, roo, etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain what you're trying to say. What do you mean by "cell name"? Are you trying to reference columns using a header (like name, date, salary) instead of A, B, C?

Comment: Hi Gavin. No, i talk about a variable that can assign to a field or range of field. (Like explained here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000704.htm)

Comment: I see. I've used `roo`, which is really good for working with Excel spreadsheets, but I don't think it has that feature. My gut says this is a pretty specific feature that most spreadsheet readers wouldn't have.

Comment: Yeah.  I agree.  I tried this post before thinking about another alternative....  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I made a named range comprised of a single cell.

The logic in my function doesn't change now, to suit your requirement:

```
Function CallFunctionFromExternalExtract() As Variant

    CallFunctionFromExternalExtract = Application.Names("MyRangeName").RefersToRange.Formula

End Function
```

You should be able to call this from your extract program, if it can enable macros.